# Can't change language and run other commands in PowerShell as an Admin

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm connected with .adm credentials to user machine and can't make any changes to the language.
I tried to install some powershell modules but with no luck. Does anybody have an idea? Maybe it's a proxy issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-languagepack-management-with-powershell/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I can't run it. I'm getting the above error

Comment: It need to be on PATH.  Where did you install the cmdlet?  Powershell will check for cmdlets if they are directly in a sub folder of any of the PowerShell paths.